# Excel sum and product with difference and multiple conditions

Tags: excel, sumproduct

I need to check inventory excess, but I have several conditions to perform this.

I already tried several SUMIFS and SUMPRODUCT without any success.

The input is:

[image]

The expected output is:

[image]

The logic is if (quantity > grossDemand) and type <> openOOOther then total excess = (quantity - grossDemand) * cost.

As I previously said the intend is to fulfill the output table with the sum grouped by largestBU.

Is it possible to be done using SUMIFS or SUMPRODUCT or any other single formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$10=G2)*($D$2:$D$10>$E$2:$E$10)*($B$2:$B$10<>"openOOOther")*(($D$2:$D$10-$E$2:$E$10)*$C$2:$C$10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. My error was I was trying to reference the full column like $D:$D, and I should do $D$2:$D$10.
I probably has to do with the headers.
Thank you!

Comment: correct, you cannot multiply strings and sumproduct does not ignore errors.